# DICOM file export SPACING using VTK

Tags: vtk, dicom, spacing

how can I get spacing value from allready oppened file. I try his but it do not work exactly. I have to save a DICOM file.

```
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> OutData = images[currentImageIndex];
    meta->SetAttributeValue(DC::PixelSpacing, OutData->GetSpacing   (double x, double y, double z);
```

Comment: Maybe you should accept or comment MrPedru22's answer? That's SO's way of saying "Thank you"

Answer (score 1):

You can get the spacing with `OutData->GetOutput()->GetSpacing()`. If you want to save a DICOM file, this could be an approach (python):

```
#Read DICOM
reader = vtk.vtkDICOMImageReader()
reader.SetFileName("sample.dcm")
reader.Update()

spacing = reader.GetOutput().GetSpacing()

newimage = vtk.vtkImageData()
newimage.SetSpacing(spacing)

writer = vtk.vtkXMLImageDataWriter()
writer.SetFileName("sample.vti")
writer.SetInput(newimage)
writer.Write()
```

This actually saves to .vti file, because there is no class in VTK to save dicom file. But you can do this with other libraries, such as [gdcm2vtk](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Gdcm2vtk)